# wrong character display in cmd windows in XP

Tags: windows, db2

When i install DB2 express-C in windows xp platform, the command windows cann't display correct chinese character, replace with wrong code display such as "??##".

How can i fix it.

Answer (score 1):

Windows Console windows don't support UTF-8. They can only show the "OEM" codepage, like in MS-DOS, or - rarely - UTF-16 Unicode.

You can try using this command

```
C:> chcp 65001
```

before running your program - 65001 is the "codepage" for UTF-8. But this is kind of an ugly hack, and only affects the window it's executed on.

Answer (score 0):

[ftp.software.ibm.com](ftp://ftp.software.ibm.com/) has all of their publicly available patches listed at this FTP site. No log in is necessary.

IBM is pretty good about getting language packs out. It is, however, a pretty large ftp site. You may want to start in the **software** section.

Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

Also, in addition to the poster above, if you choose the wrong font for your console, then you are limited in the display of characters. Use a commercial unicode font and you should have little trouble (but be aware that some "hand-coded" fonts maynot have all character positions filled in).

Comment: The default font, Lucida Console, has a pretty rich selection of Unicode characters.